# F# Deciphering a type with maps

Tags: dictionary, f#

I'm just starting out in F# and I'm wondering how to decipher the following types and what they represent from a book example:

```
type subs = Map<string,exp> option

type lp = (subs->subs) ->subs->subs // A LP computation
```

I understand the sub type is simply a map with strings and an associated exp type... but I dont understand the use of '->' and what the `lp` type is assigning...

Any help on deciphering the `lp` type would be great

Comment: `lp` is a higher-order function that returns a `subs` and takea two parameters: a function that maps a `subs` to a `subs`, and a `subs`. A loose C# signature translation would be `delegate subs lp(Func<subs, subs> x, subs y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` represents a function. For example, `string -> int` represents a function that takes a string as an argument, and returns an integer.

If you chain the `->`, you read it from right to left: `a -> b -> c -> d` is `a -> (b -> (c -> d))`.

Functions can take functions as arguments, so, `lp` is `(subs -> subs) -> subs -> subs`, which is also written as `(subs -> subs) -> (subs -> subs)`. It is a function that takes a function.
If it is confusing, try to see it as `fn -> (subs -> subs)`, where `type fn = subs -> subs`, a type for a function.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function